# Pointer to a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to understand pointers more and am having trouble with this example.

```
 typedef struct{
    int areaCode;
    int streetNumber;
 }Address;
 Address *addr;
 addr->areaCode = 10000;
 printf("%d\n", addr->areaCode);
```

I get a segmentation fault and can't seem to understand why.

addr is a pointer to a Address struct, so I also tried:

```
 *addr->areaCode = 10000;
```

and also got a "indirection requires pointer operand ", any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Address *addr;
```

You only declared a pointer `addr`, but it points to somewhere unknown. You didn't allocate memory space for it.

To fix it, change into

```
Address *addr = malloc(sizeof(Address));
```

Comment: Don't forget to free() before program termination to release the memory!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't allocated memory for structure object. Either use `malloc()` or simply declare variable of type `Address` instead of pointer to `Address` (in which case to access member use `.` operator instead of `->`).

#### Option one:

```
Address *addr = malloc(sizeof *addr); // don't forget #include <stdlib.h>
if (addr == NULL) {
    // handle failed allocation
}
// ...
free(addr); // free(addr), addr = NULL; if you like
```

#### Option two:

```
Address addr;
```

Answer (score 1):

`addr` is uninitialised and so contains some 'random' value. De-referencing an uninitialised pointer causes... problems.
Accessing memory that you are not allowed to = segmentation fault.
Accessing random memory that doesn't seg-fault leads to memory corruption.

You can do:

```
Address myAddress;
Address *addr = &myAddress;
```

and this will work.  Allocate first then aquire pointer.
This will produce a pointer to the `Address` on the stack. Beware of it going out of scope at the end of the function.

You can also do:

```
Address *addr = malloc(sizeof(Address));
```

This allocates on the heap so the actual `Address` won't go out of scope.  But you do need to remember to `free(addr);` or you introduce a memory leak.